# Double table header in backpack-for-laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I am using backpack for laravel 5.0 pro. In list page, I am getting the table header twice. Once at the up of the table, -as expected-, another table header in the bottom of the table.
[image]
My `AuthorCrudController`.

```
    protected function setupListOperation()
    {
        CRUD::column('id');
        CRUD::column('name');
        CRUD::column('bio');
        CRUD::column('image');
        CRUD::column('created_at');
        CRUD::column('updated_at');

        /**
         * Columns can be defined using the fluent syntax or array syntax:
         * - CRUD::column('price')->type('number');
         * - CRUD::addColumn(['name' => 'price', 'type' => 'number']);
         */
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is intended behavior, but you can remove it by creating a custom list view:

- Create a copy of list.blade.php by running `php artisan backpack:publish crud/list`
- Remove the `<tfoot>` element from the table

[See here](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/5.x/crud-operation-list-entries#how-to-overwrite-1) for more information on creating custom list views.